# PHP Source - own modification for function names

Tags: php

PHP is Open Source, so, I can feel free to modify this.

But am I doing it with good sense?

For example - Function names. I think it would be nice to have got some construction like this:

```
function Find($trollName)TrollIn($forestName)ForestAndKillHimBy($weaponName)Weapon();
```

Which would be equivalent to this:

```
function Find___TrollIn___ForestAndKillHimBy___Weapon(
    $trollName,
    $forestName,
    $weaponName
);
```

So I could run

```
$result = Find("ugly")TrollIn("dark")ForestAndKillHimBy("firesword")Weapon();
```

Now it looks like natural language.

Could it be good modification?

Comment: Do not modify PHP files. Your changes wouldn't be on hosting servers and Your website won't work. Make Your own functions which will be based on functions from PHP.

Comment: I considered to make parser something like twig. it would be converted to standard php before execution, but BMC showed me that my idea exists already, so, i think my method is not nessesary any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exists, it's called [fluent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) and works in PHP

Answer (score 0):

It is same for me as you write something like this:

```
function FindTrollInForestAndKillHimByWeapon($ugly,$dark,$firesword) {

 ... do something with data

}
```

I agree with Krzysztof ... do not modify PHP.